# Task distribution across microservices

Tags: microservices

We are building our first microservice architecture using Spring Boot and Kubernetes. I have a general question about scaling up one of our microservices which processes RSS feeds.

Currently we have about 100 feeds and run one instance of the microservice to process them. The feed sources are stored in a database and once the feeds are processed they are written to a central Kafka queue.

We want to increase the number of feeds and the number of instances of the microservice to process the feeds.

Are there any design patterns which I could follow to distribute the RSS feeds across the number of instances available? How would I dynamically allocate which microservice instance processes which set of feeds.

Any recommendations or best practice advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first attempt is to use some messaging system.

You could send a message that some "rss feed must be processed" with essential information about this task (feed id, link whatever).

Then make all instances implement logic of consumption from the queue.
This way, the instances will compete for processing the job. The more messages you have in the more tasks to do you'll have (obviously). You can then scale out the number of microservices.

Comment: Great thanks Mark. I'll have a go. The things that I need to think about is one instance sending a message with the feeds to process, I guess I can use some lock mechanism here. Also I need to change the polling logic as at the moment once a feed is started, the instance auto polls the feed for new content every 5 mins. What I probably need to do is stop this auto-polling and allow the messaging system to distribute this to another instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash function to distribute RSS feeds across your microservices. Lets say you have 5 instance of microservices, you can use below algorithm for assigning RSS to your microservices

```
hash_code = hashingAlgorithm(rss)
node_id = hash_code % num_of_nodes // 5 in this case
get_service(node_id).send(rss)
```

The process of assigning RSS to your microservices is also can be scaled easily, you can launch 3 independent process to read from your DB and assigning RSS to microservices without any coordination.